# Create contact with a custom field

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I'm trying to create contact with a custom field, as detailed in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/custom-field#setvaluevalue).
So I've tried to use this code, from the documentation:

```
var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByName('John Doe');
var field = contacts[0].getCustomFields()[0];
field.setLabel('Mail application');
field.setValue('Gmail');
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'setLabel' of undefined

Any thoughts?

---

Here's my complete code, to which I'd like to be able to add a custom field named "ID number":

```
var clientaddress = spreadsheet.getRange('L2').getValue();
  var clientcontact = ContactsApp.createContact(clientfirstname, clientlastname, clientemail);
    var contactgroup = spreadsheet.getRange('AL2').getValue(); // AL2 has the group name
    var group = ContactsApp.getContactGroup(contactgroup);
    clientcontact = clientcontact.addToGroup(group);
    var address = clientcontact.addAddress(ContactsApp.Field.HOME_ADDRESS,clientaddress);
    var phone = clientcontact.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MOBILE_PHONE, clientmobile);  
    var IDnumber = ?
```

---

Here's the code I'm trying to run as a test:

```
function quicktest () {
 var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByName('XXXX');
 var IDnumber = contacts.addCustomField("IDnumber","12345");
}
```

---

OK, so now that we know it's an array, I added the [0] to the code but still no joy.I made sure to chose a contact that has no duplicates, so I'll be sure it's editing the right contact.

```
function quicktest () {
 var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByName('XXX');
  var IDnumber = contacts[0].addCustomField("IDnumber","12345");
}
```

Here's the screenshot of the contact "more details" page.
[image]

---

Yes, it's working now :)
Thanks to everyone!
Revised code:

```
function quicktest () {
 var contacts = ContactsApp.createContact("test1", "familytest1", "email@email.com").getId();
 ContactsApp.getContactById(contacts).addCustomField("IDnumber","12345");
}
```

Screenshot from Google ContactS:
[image]

Comment: What "type" does `getConactsByName()` return?

Comment: Not sure, see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getcontactsbynamequery)

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed it returns an array. However, this might prove to be an issue as we might have several contacts with the same name. I thought that if we add this custom field during the contact initial setup, we can make sure we are indeed working only on that contact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> field.setLabel('Mail application');

> Cannot read property 'setLabel' of undefined

The error says that `field` is `undefined` and that it cannot read a property called `setLabel` in `undefined`(because `undefined` doesn't have such a method; only customField class does).

`field` is `undefined`, because  the contact "John Doe" doesn't have a custom field associated with it.

Use [`Contact.addCustomField("fieldName","fieldValue")`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contact#addcustomfieldlabel,-content) to add a custom field to a contact:

```
clientcontact.addCustomField("IDnumber","12345");
```

Comment: Thanks. I cannot get the syntax to work. I'm updating the question, perhaps it'll be clearer.

Comment: Thanks @TheMaster, but still no go. Here's the error: TypeError: contacts.addCustomField is not a function

Comment: @user13708028 Add the current script and the exact text of the error to your question